# C++ Pointer to a function which takes an instance of a templated class as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have trouble compiling a class, which has function pointers as member variables. The pointers are to functions which take an instance of a class as argument.

Like

```
template<class T, int N>
double (*f)(Vector<T,N> v);
```

I get "error: data member 'f' cannot be a member template" Compiler is gcc 4.2.

**Edit**

Before using templates I just had

```
double (*f)(Vector v);
```

This also works

```
double (*f)(Vector<double,2> v)
```

But I would like to have a function pointer for a function which takes a generic Vector as argument..

Comment: Can you post the signature of a function that `f` can point to?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful for suggesting what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a member `typedef`:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Vector
{
public:

    /// type of function pointer
    typedef double (*FuncPtr)( const Vector& );

};

// concrete type
typedef Vector<double,10> VecDouble10;

// actual function
double func( const VecDouble10>& );

// usage
VecDouble10::FuncPtr fp = func;
```

Comment: I don't understand the first typedef, what would be the alias name for the function pointer?

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more, why should it work with typedef if it does not without it?

Comment: There's no magic - it's just a "template" for a concrete `typedef` in a specialized template. You can explicitly use a type like `double (*FP)( const Vector<double,10>& )`, `typedef` just makes it cleaner.

Comment: Humm I still don't understand it.. Why are you just using const Vector & in the function pointer, shouldn't it be const vector<T,N>& if it's templated?

Comment: Because it's within the template definition - template parameters are assumed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a "template pointer", you could try a function object. The example below adds `1.0` to the wrapped function template.

```
struct AcceptsVector {
  template<typename T, int N>
  double operator()(Vector<T,N> v) const { return 1.0 + real_f(v); }
};

AcceptsVector f;
```

The difference to a "real" template pointer is that you cannot re-seat "AcceptsVector" to call another template, like you can do with normal function pointers. The binding is hardcoded at compile-time. However you can pass along `f` like a function pointer, and can call `f` with any `Vector<T, N>` like a template.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't quite valid c++, basically what you're looking for are template-template parameters.

http://www.progdoc.de/papers/ttp/psi-ttp/psi-ttp.html
explains all about them

Generally, if you get yourself into this situation, you want to find a workaroumd, because your code becomes illegible VERY quickly

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler doesn't know at the compile time, how many `f`'s are you going to have (one for each possible `T` and `N`?). Therefore the compiler cannot calculate how much memory do objects of your class need. That's why such constructs are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a templated pointer to function, that makes no sense.
But what you can do is

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void foo(const std::vector<T>& v) {
   // do something
}

void (*ptr_foo)(const std::vector<int>&) = &foo<int>;
```

*(here the function pointers a templated function, which template argument is explicitly set to `int`)*

Answer (score 0):

Because your code makes just as much sense as:

```
struct X
{
  template < typename T >
  std::vector<T> vect;
};
```

You're trying to make a member *variable* a template.  This is just not a valid C++ construct and I seriously doubt it ever will be.

How do you do what you actually want?  I'm not sure since I don't know what you actually are trying to accomplish and why.